# Properly mocking libraries/methods with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to write a unit test for a method and I'm having some trouble getting things to run smoothly.

I need to test the only `public` method in this class, `AuthenticateAdminService.authAdmin`, which makes calls to the `private` methods, which make calls to third party libraries like `jsonwebtoken` and `bcrypt`. The prolem I'm running into is when I try to compare passwords with `bcrypt` it returns as `false` during automated-tests but `true` during manual-testing.

How am I supposed to reliably mock these private methods and libraries? I found a few posts here on SO that did nothing for me, perhaps I just didn't understand the answers. I found [this post on mocking libraries](https://wanago.io/2018/09/17/javascript-testing-tutorial-part-four-mocking-api-calls-and-simulating-react-components-interactions/) which really helped for a moment until I realized that any library I'm using is wrapped inside a private method which does me no good in my tests as I'm not directly calling the mocked library.

I think I'm supposed to create a mock of the `AuthenticateAdminService` class private methods. Test the actual public method, `authAdmin`, and somehow get the mocked private methods called instead of the real versions. Any help?

## AuthenticateAdminService

```
class AuthenticateAdminService {

  public static async authAdmin(reqBody: RequestBody, AdminModel: AdminModel): Promise<object> {
    const { username, password } = reqBody
    const adminRow: AdminRow = await AdminModel.findOne({ where: { username } })
    let token: { token?: string } = {}
    if (adminRow !== null) {
      token = await AuthenticateAdminService.checkIfPasswordsMatch(password, adminRow)
    }
    return token
  }


  private static async checkIfPasswordsMatch(plainPassword: string, adminRow: AdminRow): Promise<object> {
    const isPasswordsMatch = await Promise.resolve(bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, adminRow.password))
    let token: object = {}
    if (isPasswordsMatch) {
      const admin: object = AuthenticateAdminService.removePasswordPropFromAdminRow(adminRow)
      token = { token: await AuthenticateAdminService.createToken(admin) }
    }
    return token
  }

  private static removePasswordPropFromAdminRow(adminRow: AdminRow): object {
    const { password, ...admin } = adminRow.dataValues
    return admin
  }

  private static async createToken(admin: object): Promise<string> {
    const token: string = await Promise.resolve(jwt.sign({ admin }, 'expressadminarea'))
    return token
  }

}
```

## AuthenticateAdminService.test.js (fails)

```
import { AuthenticateAdminService } from '../../src/services/AuthenticateAdminService/AuthenticateAdminService'

type AdminModel = {
  findOne(where: object): AdminRow
}

type AdminRow = {
  password: string
  dataValues: { password: string }
}

test('authAdmin', async () => {
  const reqBody: { username: string, password: string } = { username: 'foo', password: 'foo' }
  const adminModel: AdminModel = { findOne: (_where) => <AdminRow>{ password: 'foo', dataValues: { password: 'foo' } } }
  const token: { token?: string } = await AuthenticateAdminService.authAdmin(reqBody, adminModel)

  expect(typeof token).toBe('object')
  expect(typeof token.token).toBe('string')  // token.token is undefined
  expect(token.token.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to mock your `adminModel` with a password hash instead of the plaintext password:

```
test('authAdmin', async () => {
  const reqBody: { username: string, password: string } = { username: 'foo', password: 'foo' }
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash('foo', 10);  // create a hash
  const adminModel: AdminModel = { findOne: (_where) => <AdminRow>{ password: hash, dataValues: { password: hash } } }  // use the hash
  const token: { token?: string } = await AuthenticateAdminService.authAdmin(reqBody, adminModel)

  expect(typeof token).toBe('object')
  expect(typeof token.token).toBe('string')  // Success!
  expect(token.token.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
})
```

---

Also, `bcrypt.compare` returns a `Promise` so you can simplify that line:

```
const isPasswordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, adminRow.password);
```